# Batch: Calculating time elapsed from timestamps

Tags: batch-file

guys, i have a task to analyze some log files like this one:

```
12:03:11 Testing Import (test #240.)
12:10:47 Testing Searches (test #241.)
12:14:39 Testing Default notifications (test #242.)
12:20:05 Testing Inventory list monitor (test #243.)
12:34:31 Testing Reports from console (test #244.)
12:40:05 Testing Users and user groups (test #245.)
12:43:33      ERROR: 1024 characters in field Name, warning not shown!
12:48:13 Testing RDE (test #246.)
```

and my job would be to calculate time elapsed on each test and write it to another txt file. Of course lines like this one

`12:43:33      ERROR: 1024 characters in field Name, warning not shown!`

should not be taken into account. So this string `(test #` can be taken as some kind of identifier. Preferable language is batch but I have really limited experience with it so any help would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: is batch a requirement? it's not really best suited for such tasks; even can be done if no other option, but normally I would suggest something  like python or even dedicated log-parsing solution like graylog, etc.

Comment: There is no date entry, so duration calculations might not be reliable...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Vairis: batch is not a requirement, but i need something that will work natively on Windows. Python is great, and I more familiar with it, but I would have to install it on that specific system.

Comment: @aschipfl: I'm aware of that, thank You. I will think of something.
.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I had some general idea how to do it and I have tried do some coding, but it wasn't much. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q39619700.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "starthh="
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=: " %%a IN (
 'findstr /L /c:"(test #" "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF DEFINED starthh (
  CALL :report 1%%a 1%%b 1%%c
 ) ELSE (
  SET /a starthh=1%%a&SET /a startmm=1%%b&SET /a startss=1%%c
 )
 SET "event=%%d"
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:report
SET /a starthh=((%1-starthh)*3600)+((%2-startmm)*60)+%3-startss
IF %starthh% lss 0 SET /a starthh+=3600*24
:: If in seconds
ECHO %starthh% seconds FOR %event%
:: If in hh:mm:ss
SET /a startss=100+(starthh %% 60)
SET /a startmm=100+((starthh-startss+100) %% 3600) / 60
SET /a starthh=100+(starthh/3600)
ECHO %starthh:~-2%:%startmm:~-2%:%startss:~-2% FOR %event%
SET /a starthh=%1
SET /a startmm=%2
SET /a startss=%3
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q39619700.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

For each entry in the log, filtered by using `findstring` to locate only those lines containing `(test #`, record the start time elements and the event text.

Processing is simply a matter of subtracting the new time elements from the old, calculating the result and reproducing the old event text with the calculated elapsed time; then re-setting the time elements from the latest line. Note the use of `1` preceding the time-element strings to overcome the leading-zero-is-octal problem.

Comment: Fantastic, just the thing I need. You will get your +1 once I have sufficient reputation.